# Shopping cart doesn not go to payment gateway, instead returns to a page "Shopping cart is Empty"

Tags: payment, shopping-cart, payment-gateway

The shopping cart on proceeding for any mode of payment, leads directly to http://www.kkeautocare.com/checkout/cart/ which shows :

Shopping Cart is Empty

You have no items in your shopping cart.

Click here to continue shopping.

Tried almost everything I could find on Internet. Can somebody please help?

Comment: I read at several places about cookie transfer between http and https, so I bought an SSL certificate as well. Still the same issue.